# Отправить данные в уже открытый stage с помощью контроллера javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Кратко: 
Есть 2 **открытых** `Stage` с кнопками. По нажатии на которые они должны передавать данные друг другу с помощью контроллеров, например менять текст `Label` друг у друга.

Описание кода: 
Существует программа, состоящая из двух окон, их fxml файлов и контроллеров. Сначала открывается первое окно, в котором есть кнопка и лейбл. По нажатии на кнопку, открывается второе такое же окно. Во втором окне лейбл изначально содержит текст "smth", при открытии с помощью связи контроллеров, лейбл меняет текст на "new text" (передал текст для примера). Я попытался сделать похожую передачу из второго окна в первый, но мне выдает ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "testfxapp.FirstWindowController.sendToFirst(String)" because "controller" is null
    at testfxapp.SecondWindowController.secondAction(SecondWindowController.java:21)
    ... 58 more
```

Цель: во втором окне присутствует кнопка, по нажатии на которую в уже открытом первом окне должен измениться текст лейбла. В идеале по нажатии кнопок в своих окнах, должны менять текст в другом.

Посмотрел большинство роликов с контроллерами и не нашел подобного, на стеке нашел только один пост похожий, но там странный способ и мне кажется есть более простой до которого я не могу дойти сам.

[Ссылка на пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959096/using-javafx-to-pass-data-to-an-already-opened-window)

Код:

**Отсюда запускается приложение "firstWindow.java"**

```
package testfxapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class firstWindow extends Application{
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("firstWindow.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

**FXML-файл "firstWindow.fxml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testfxapp.FirstWindowController" >
    <Label text="smth good" fx:id="firstLabel" />
    <Button text="accept" fx:id="firstBut" onAction="#firstAction" />
</VBox>
```

**Первый контроллер "FirstWindowController"**

```
package testfxapp;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FirstWindowController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Label firstLabel;
    
    @FXML
    Button firstBut;
    
    @FXML
    private void firstAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("secondWindow.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        SecondWindowController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.sendToSecond("new text");
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void sendToFirst(String text) {
        firstLabel.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

**FXML-файл второго окна "secondWindow.fxml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testfxapp.SecondWindowController">
    <Label text="smth" fx:id="secondLabel" />
    <Button text="accept" fx:id="secondBut" onAction="#secondAction" />
</VBox>
```

**Контроллер второго окна "SecondWindowController.java"**

```
package testfxapp;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SecondWindowController implements Initializable {

    @FXML Label secondLabel;
    @FXML Button secondBut;
    
    @FXML
    private void secondAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("firstWindow.fxml"));
        FirstWindowController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.sendToFirst("new text 2");
    }
    
    public void sendToSecond(String text) {  
        secondLabel.setText(text);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать ваш первый контроллер второму.

Добавьте поле-ссылку на первый контроллер

```
public class SecondWindowController implements Initializable {


    public static FirstWindowController controller1;
    // Доступ к первому контроллеру


    @FXML Label secondLabel;
    @FXML Button secondBut;

    @FXML
    private void secondAction(ActionEvent event) {
     controller1.sendToFirst("new text 2");
    }
```

При нажатии кнопки из первого контроллера, передайте копию первого контроллера - второму.

```
   @FXML
    private void firstAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("secondWindow.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        SecondWindowController.controller1 = this;   //Тут передаем первый контроллер второму
        stage.show();
    }
```

Конечно это моветон и меня должны закидать гнилыми помидорами за публичный static. Но поскольку Controller подразумевается как final, то я думаю в этом ничего страшного нет.
Скопировал ваш код к себе, у меня все работает.
Успехов вам.